# Union of two class vectors in C++

Tags: c++, vector

My problem is the following:

I have two vectors of an specific class called "estado" (state):

```
class estado {
vector <int> prev_estados;
int g;          //coste camino
int h;          //heuristica
int f;          //total
bus autobus;
vector<estado> estados_anteriores;
int n_estudiantes;                             //numero de lo de abajo
vector<vector<estudiante>> estudiantes;               //lista de todos los estudiantes que faltan por subirse al autobus. En el momento que un alumno se sube al autobus, se le elimina
                                                //la lista de estudiantes tiene la forma de [parada_de_origen][simplemente el orden en que se metieron]
```

Contructor of estado:

```
estado(vector<int> prev_esta, int G, vector<estado> estados_ant, int n_estudiantess,
       vector<vector<estudiante>> estudiantess, int parada_destino, bus autobus) : autobus(autobus) {
    prev_estados = prev_esta;
    g = G;
    h = n_estudiantess*4;
    f = g+h;
    estados_anteriores = estados_ant;
    n_estudiantes = n_estudiantess;                //numero que quedan por dejar
    estudiantes = estudiantess;
}
```

And I want to merge them in a single ordered vector using a pre defined function:

```
bool comparator(estado a, estado b){
if(a.getNEstudiantes()==b.getNEstudiantes()){
    if(a.getBus().get_NCarga()==b.getBus().get_NCarga()){
        //Aqui se puede implementar homogeneidad de alumnos en el bus
        if(a.getG()==b.getG()){
            return true;
        }else{
            //Por una cosa que dijo en clase seria mejor poner que se priorice la G mas grande
            return a.getG() > b.getG();
        }
    }else{
        //Cuantos mas niños haya en el bus mejor
        return a.getBus().get_NCarga() > b.getBus().get_NCarga();
    }
}else{
    //Cuantos menos estudiantes queden por entregar mejor
    return a.getNEstudiantes() < b.getNEstudiantes();
}
```

}

Doing some research I came out with the function "set_union", which must be used this way:

```
vector<estado> v(10);
vector<estado>:: iterator it;
it= set_union(big.begin(),big.end(),small.begin(),small.end(),v.begin(),comparator);    //unirse ordenadamene en v
big[a]=v;
```

In fact I receive the following building error:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_tempbuf.h:60:0,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:62,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/algorithm:62,
             from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/regex:38,
             from /cygdrive/c/Users/dasan/CLionProjects/Heuristica_2_2/bus.h:10,
             from /cygdrive/c/Users/dasan/CLionProjects/Heuristica_2_2/heuristic.h:5,
             from /cygdrive/c/Users/dasan/CLionProjects/Heuristica_2_2/heuristic.cpp:5:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of 'void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = estado; _Args = {}]':
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:527:18:   required from 'static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_1<_TrivialValueType>::__uninit_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = estado*; _Size = long unsigned int; bool _TrivialValueType = false]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:583:20:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n(_ForwardIterator, _Size) [with _ForwardIterator = estado*; _Size = long unsigned int]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:645:44:   required from '_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_default_n_a(_ForwardIterator, _Size, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _ForwardIterator = estado*; _Size = long unsigned int; _Tp = estado]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:1352:36:   required from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_default_initialize(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type) [with _Tp = estado; _Alloc = std::allocator<estado>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int]'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:285:30:   required from 'std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type, const allocator_type&) [with _Tp = estado; _Alloc = std::allocator<estado>; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size_type = long unsigned int; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<estado>]'
/cygdrive/c/Users/dasan/CLionProjects/Heuristica_2_2/heuristic.cpp:83:63:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.4.0/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: no matching function for call to 'estado::estado()'
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

With my basic understancing of c++ I think that the error is in the line

```
vector<estado> v(10);
```

With the "(10)" part. In fact if I dont include that, the vector will have no room for store the things inserted and I will receive a Segmentation Error.

What I should do? I appreciate all your help.

EDIT: As @txtechhelp point out, the issue was that my class "estado" doesnt have a default controcutor.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: On the `set_union` line, change `v.begin()` to `back_inserter(v)`.

Comment: The error `no matching function for call to 'estado::estado()'` would indicate you do not have a default constructor for your `estado` class which is what is being called when you try to make `vector<estado> v(10);` (which creates 10 default constructed instances of `estado`). Do you only have the 1 ctor?